# How to get only first certain tags with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get first 3  tags texts using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and collecting those in array.

The table is like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Floyd</td>
            <td>Machine</td>
            <td>Banking</td>
            <td>HelpScout</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nirvana</td>
            <td>Paper</td>
            <td>Business</td>
            <td>GuitarTuna</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>The edge</td>
            <td>Tree</td>
            <td>Hospital</td>
            <td>Sician</td>
        </tr>

        .....
        .....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I am trying to achieve is collect these in arrays excluding the 4th `td` of the `tr` tag:

```
array(
   array(
      'art' => 'Floyd',
      'thing' => 'machine',
      'passion' => 'Banking',
   ),
   array(
      'art' => 'Nirvana',
      'thing' => 'Paper',
      'passion' => 'Business',
   ),
   array(
      'art' => 'The edge',
      'thing' => 'Tree',
      'passion' => 'Hospital',
   ),
);
```

This is what I have tried is:

```
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/library/simple_html_dom.php';

$html    = file_get_html( 'https://www.example.com/list.html' );
$collect = array();
$list    = $html->find( 'table tbody tr td' );

foreach( $list as $l ) {
    $collect[] = $l->plaintext;
}

$html->clear();
unset($html);

print_r($collect);
```

Which is giving all the `td`s in array and it's being difficult to identify the array keys which I require. Is there any solution for me?

Comment: Maybe iterate over the `tr` so you can grab the first 3 `td` of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of iterating over all `td` elements at once, you can iterate over each `tr` and for each tr, iterate over inner td elements and skip the 4th td:

```
$htmlString =<<<html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Floyd</td>
            <td>Machine</td>
            <td>Banking</td>
            <td>HelpScout</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nirvana</td>
            <td>Paper</td>
            <td>Business</td>
            <td>GuitarTuna</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>The edge</td>
            <td>Tree</td>
            <td>Hospital</td>
            <td>Sician</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
html;
$html = str_get_html($htmlString);

// find all tr tags
$trs = $html->find('table tr');
$collect = [];

// foreach tr tag, find its td children
foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    $tds = $tr->find('td');
    // collect first 3 children and skip the 4th
    $collect []= [
        'art' => $tds[0]->plaintext,
        'thing' => $tds[1]->plaintext,
        'passion' => $tds[2]->plaintext,
    ];
}
print_r($collect);
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [art] => Floyd
            [thing] => Machine
            [passion] => Banking
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [art] => Nirvana
            [thing] => Paper
            [passion] => Business
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [art] => The edge
            [thing] => Tree
            [passion] => Hospital
        )

)
```